# Why is this code throwing an error in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I'm trying to solve this problem on Stepik: The dataframe with the name `my_stat` contains 4 columns: `session_value`, `group`, `time`, `n_users`. In the variables `n_users`, we replaced all negative values ​​with the median value of `n_users` (excluding negative values, of course). Here's what I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd    
import numpy as np

my_stat = my_stat['session_value'].replace(np.nan, 0)
my_stat.loc[my_stat['n_users'] < 0, 'n_users'] = my_stat['n_users'].median()
```

But I get this error:

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 25, in <module>
    med = my_stat['n_users'].median()
  File "/home/stepic/instances/master-plugins/sandbox/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 871, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/home/stepic/instances/master-plugins/sandbox/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4405, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 90, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 135, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi", line 109, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'n_users'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It would be helpful to see `my_stat`...

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward, `my_stat` has no key `'n_users'`, did you try printing `my_stat` to see what it is...?

Comment: The line `my_stat = my_stat['session_value'].replace(np.nan, 0)` reassigns `my_stat` to a Series. You probably wanted `my_stat['session_value'] = my_stat['session_value'].replace(np.nan, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line

```
my_stat = my_stat['session_value'].replace(np.nan, 0)
```

to this

```
my_stat['session_value'] = my_stat['session_value'].replace(np.nan, 0)
```

**Or, even better, use `fillna`:**

```
my_stat['session_value'] = my_stat['session_value'].fillna(0)
```